# colcon builds "in-source"

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, colcon, build, ros-bouncy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Opposed to the documentation provided [here](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Tutorials/Colcon-Tutorial/#id4) `colcon build` creates the output directories "log", "install" and "build" in place.

Considering I have packages in `src` the commands `roscd <my_fancy_ros_package>; colcon build` would create a workspace structure:

```
workspace
  - src
      - <my_fancy_ros_package>
          - build
          - log
          - install 
          - (other directories contained in <my_fancy_ros_packag> like "msg", "include" …
```

to have the output directories as peers of "src" I have to change directory up to "workspace" (`roscd <my_fancy_ros_package>; cd ../..; colcon build`

Are there any (undocumented) options I somehow set to disable out-out-source builds? I have the following colcon packages installed (from bouncy setup instructions as far as I remember)

```
python3-colcon-argcomplete/bionic,bionic,bionic,bionic,now 0.3.0-1 all [installed,automatic]
python3-colcon-bash/bionic,bionic,bionic,bionic,now 0.3.1-1 all [installed,automatic]
python3-colcon-bazel/bionic,bionic,bionic,bionic 0.1.0-1 all
python3-colcon-cmake/bionic,bionic,bionic,bionic,now 0.2.5-1 all [installed,automatic]
python3-colcon-common-extensions/bionic,bionic,bionic,bionic,now 0.2.0-2 all [installed]
python3-colcon-core/bionic,bionic,bionic,bionic,now 0.3.14-1 all [installed,automatic]
python3-colcon-defaults/bionic,bionic,bionic,bionic,now 0.2.1-1 all [installed,automatic]
python3-colcon-devtools/bionic,bionic,bionic,bionic,now 0.2.1-1 all [installed,automatic]
python3-colcon-library-path/bionic,bionic,bionic,bionic,now 0.2.0-1 all [installed,automatic]
python3-colcon-metadata/bionic,bionic,bionic,bionic,now 0.2.1-1 all [installed,automatic]
python3-colcon-mixin/bionic,bionic,bionic,bionic 0.1.1-1 all
python3-colcon-notification/bionic,bionic,bionic,bionic,now 0.2.5-1 all [installed,automatic]
python3-colcon-output/bionic,bionic,bionic,bionic,now 0.2.3-1 all [installed,automatic]
python3-colcon-package-information/bionic,bionic,bionic,bionic,now 0.2.1-1 all [installed,automatic]
python3-colcon-package-selection/bionic,bionic,bionic,bionic,now 0.2.1-1 all [installed,automatic]
python3-colcon-parallel-executor/bionic,bionic,bionic,bionic,now 0.2.2-1 all [installed,automatic]
python3-colcon-pkg-config/bionic,bionic,bionic,bionic,now 0.1.0-1 all [installed,automatic]
python3-colcon-powershell/bionic,bionic,bionic,bionic,now 0.3.3-1 all [installed,automatic]
python3-colcon-python-setup-py/bionic,bionic,bionic,bionic,now 0.2.1-1 all [installed,automatic]
python3-colcon-recursive-crawl/bionic,bionic,bionic,bionic,now 0.2.0-1 all [installed,automatic]
python3-colcon-ros/bionic,bionic,bionic,bionic,now 0.3.6-1 all [installed,automatic]
python3-colcon-test-result/bionic,bionic,bionic,bionic,now 0.3.0-1 all [installed,automatic]
python3-colcon-zsh/bionic,bionic,bionic,bionic,now 0.3.1-1 all [installed,automatic]
```

this happens with ros2 (bouncy) and ros1 (melodic) workspaces, regardless of which ROS_DISTRO is set

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/312691/colcon-builds-%22in-source%22/) by [ipa-jba](https://answers.ros.org/users/3541/ipa-jba/) on ROS Answers with karma: 153 on 2019-01-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The documentation you referenced doesn't mention to invoke `colcon build` in the package directory but in the root of the workspace.

`colcon` doesn't support invoking the command in a subdirectory of the workspace (without providing custom paths to `--build-base`, `--install-base`, `--log-base`, `--base-paths`) - see https://github.com/colcon/colcon-core/issues/139 for the same feature request.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2019-01-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0